# How to enable wheel group in solaris 11.3

Tags: sudo, solaris, group

I want to add user in wheel group but can not find wheel group in /etc/group file.

Also i uncomment the line "%wheel" in sudoers file as:

```
root@solaris:~# grep wheel /etc/sudoers
## Uncomment to allow members of group wheel to execute any command
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
#%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I need your support to enable wheel group in solaris.

Answer (score 2):

By default, there is no `wheel` group in Solaris. What you will have to do is to create it yourself so that the line in `/etc/sudoers` will take effect which allows you to add users to the group to have sudoer rights.